# NtQuerySystemInformation - Memory Leak

Tags: c, winapi, memory-leaks

I am enumerating all processes by running `NtQuerySystemInformation` in a loop. Before I call the main loop, I loop `NtQuerySystemInformation` until the `return value != STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH`. This way I know that there is enough memory in the allocated buffer to fit all the process names and their information structures.

I iterate the `PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure by taking the base value that I allocated for this structure and adding the `NextEntryOffset` value to it, until `NextEntryOffset != NULL`.

So the problem is, after I tried to `free` the memory allocated by this structure, I get a breakpoint on `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer`.

I am assuming this is because I've already iterated to the end of the structure and there is no reference to the beginning of the structure (which I originally allocated).

My question is, how can I get a reference to the original value so I can properly free the structure, or what is the proper way to free it without getting this breakpoint?

Comment: Post your code. Unless others can see your code, they cannot help you. Always try to [create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when you post a question.

Comment: BTW, the loop over the buffer is done when `NextEntryOffset == 0`, not when `NextEntryOffset != NULL`. You have the logic negated, plus you shouldn't compare a non-pointer such as an `unisigned long` to `NULL`. C is very forgiving, but semantically `NULL` is a pointer, and it's just good style to make this distinction clear in your code.

Comment: How so ... `for (;pSysInfo->NextEntryOffset != 0;)` ? Looks right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a pointer to the original address of the buffer before updating where the pointer structure points to (only for the first pointer address). Then you can use the backup of the start to buffer for the memory freeing later on once you're done with the buffer. That is all you need to do if you need the buffer free'd later on, but need to update to where the pointer structure points to whilst performing work with it.

Comment: Thats exactly what I do with regards to allocation. I just reallocate based on the RetLength, but I still check for `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH` because its possible that since the previous call, a new process could be added to the table and hence the size would need to be reallocated to fit the new table size. But thanks for the first paragraph!

Comment: The length could change between calls, so it requires a loop that checks for `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH` and reallocates the buffer. If a call is likely to work with a smallish buffer (less than 8 KiB), then start with a stack allocation that should work in most cases. But this `SystemProcessInformation` query should just start with 0, since it requires a fairly large heap-allocated buffer.

Comment: @ImmortaleVBR You see most doing it, since most just copy/paste and don't know the code they build.